# Network not working for some domains only on one device

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns, ipv4

A few days ago my wireless **stopped working for most domains**.
Some domains that still work are google, facebook, youtube. Notworking examples: stripe.com, stackoverflow.com, slack.com

The problem persists on different browsers (I tested Chrome, Edge and Firefox).
The network works with other noteboods and smartphones. 
I can connect to three other public networks. So the hardware should be fine.

Chrome gives me the ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error.

I already tried:

- Setting IPv4 DNS adress to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (google DNS server)
- Reset Firewall
- Reset Network settings
- Run `ipconfig /flushdns` in command prompt
- Setting the MTU to below 1500 as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1220864/brand-new-pc-only-loads-some-domains-when-on-wifi)

(Basically all solutions from [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-networking/internet-connected-but-only-googlecom-works/8e66232e-78b0-4062-bb4f-1e4cdd59ee69) and [here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2176175/internet-connected-loads-google-websites.html))

I ran a `tracert www.stackoverflow.com` and this is the output:

```
C:\Users\username>tracert www.stackoverflow.com

Routenverfolgung zu stackoverflow.com [151.101.65.69]
über maximal 30 Hops:

  1     *     192.168.1.1  meldet: Zielnetz nicht erreichbar.

Ablaufverfolgung beendet.
```

"Zielnetz nicht erreichbar" means "Targetnetwork not reachable"

If I do USB Tethering from my smartphone that is connected to the same network to the notebook it works perfectly fine and the tracert result is:

```
C:\Users\username>tracert www.stackoverflow.com
Routenverfolgung zu stackoverflow.com [151.101.193.69]
über maximal 30 Hops:

1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.42.129
2     5 ms     2 ms     3 ms  speedport.ip [192.168.2.1]
3    15 ms    11 ms    10 ms  62.155.242.164
4    19 ms    18 ms    21 ms  217.239.47.22
5    25 ms    17 ms    16 ms  ffm-b4-link.telia.net [213.248.93.186]
6    16 ms    15 ms    16 ms  fastly-ic-319195-ffm-b4.c.telia.net [213.248.84.207]
7    19 ms    18 ms    16 ms  151.101.193.69

Ablaufverfolgung beendet.
```

In adapter settings the status on the wireless shows IPv4 as "no connection" and IPv6 as connected.

Does anyone know **what the problem is** and **how to fix it**?

PS: I use Win10 with all Updates installed (Version 1803 Build 17134.523)
I had one VPN client installed but that has been removed since.

EDIT:
As proposed in the comments I tried:

- [Truly reset the TCP/IP Stack](https://ttcshelbyville.wordpress.com/2018/02/25/truly-reset-the-tcpip-stack/)
  That did not work either and all "netsh [...] reset" commands had a "access denied" problem at one line

EDIT 2: Output of "route print" command

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 17...3e 67 be cc 6e ea ......Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device
 10...c6 9d ed 9e 73 36 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 15...c6 9d ed 9e 76 36 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
  9...c4 9d ed 9e 72 37 ......Marvell AVASTAR Wireless-AC Network Controller
  8...c4 9d ed 9e 72 38 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.132     50
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   192.168.42.129   192.168.42.103     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.132    306
    192.168.1.132  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.132    306
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.132    306
     192.168.42.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.42.103    281
   192.168.42.103  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.42.103    281
   192.168.42.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.42.103    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.132    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.42.103    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.132    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.42.103    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  9    306 ::/0                     fe80::1
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  9    306 2003:ee:abd6:1883::/64   On-link
  9    306 2003:ee:abd6:1883:4daa:df45:e92a:d183/128
                                    On-link
  9    306 2003:ee:abd6:1883:f036:66dd:1d5e:1f2e/128
                                    On-link
  9    306 fe80::/64                On-link
 17    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 17    281 fe80::6927:1255:68b7:b3fa/128
                                    On-link
  9    306 fe80::f036:66dd:1d5e:1f2e/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
  9    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 17    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: `In adapter settings the status on the wireless shows IPv4 as "no connection"` I believe that's the issue. You'll need to figure out what has happened with your IPv4 connection. Try other wireless adapter, try wired connection and so on.

Comment: Do you have any ideas that I can follow?

Comment: As I wrote - try other wireless adapter, try wired connection. 

You could also try to reset Windows TCP stack https://ttcshelbyville.wordpress.com/2018/02/25/truly-reset-the-tcpip-stack/

But I'd suggest you to make sure first that the hardware is OK.

Comment: I guess the hard ware is fine. I can connect to at least three different networks I have in my mind right now. (all public ones)

Comment: I will try to reset the Windows TCP stack now

Comment: I tried the TCP stack reset now as explained in the link - thank you.
But it still does not work. Nothing changed.
Interesting: All "netsh [...] reset" operations faild at one point. (Resetting Resolve Neighbor -> then the 5th reset failed)

Comment: Have you done resetting in elevated cmd?

Comment: Yes I did that. I used Powershell with admin privileg

Comment: I'd still suggest you to try other wireless adapter with the current access point.

Comment: I am on a SurfaceBook2 so I guess I can't just change the adapter? Or do you mean that I should buy an external Wireless Adapter?

Comment: Yes, any external wireless adapter.

Comment: ok thank you for your help so far - I will try to get ahold of one asap

Comment: It looks like a routing problem on your router. I have no idea how that would occur for just one client. Did you ever do any tinkering on your router? Have you tried wiping the configuration out on your router? Although I think it is a router problem, try a 'route print' in command prompt on the problem PC and paste the output in your question. This will just display the routing table on your PC. I just want to make sure that VPN didn't leave any garbage in your routing table.

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you for the suggestion. I edited the question with the output.

Comment: About the router tinkering: I do not have access to the router. But I can and will ask my landlord about that. All other devices did not have to re-enter the password etc. So if things where changed, they did not effect any other device in any "noticable" way.
Can a router config cause such problems for one client only? (I am certain that my landlord did NOT block me or tried to do any harm on purpose)

Comment: The access denied problem is likely because you were not running from an elevated command prompt. That aside, I encountered this problem a few years ago and the solution was to modify the MTU as you first mentioned. Try more granular numbers like 1420, 1430,1440 etc... That was the solution that worked for me. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Allthough I am sure that my first attempt was in an elevated cmd prompt, I tried it again real quick. Same output... 
About the MTU: I did now try everything from 1300 to 1500 in steps of 10. Unforntunatelly it did not help.

Comment: It ended up working at some point wihtout any further actions. I will leave this question here for people to maybe find approaches.